# Indy-sdk building error: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: xcode, rust-cargo, hyperledger-indy

I was trying to build indy-sdk manually (auto-build didnt work) from the [hyperledger docs](https://hyperledger-indy.readthedocs.io/projects/sdk/en/latest/docs/build-guides/mac-build.html)
macOS Monterey 12.6.6, Xcode 14.0.1, terminal zsh 
related libraries installed: pkg-config, libsodium 1.0.12, automake, autoconf, cmake, openssl 1.1, zeromq, zmq

At step 6 when I set environment variable with this command I am getting the following error:

```
    export LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/sdk/libindy/target/<config>
    zsh: parse error near `\n'
```

Then I tried to set the env var with the code below

```
    export LIBRARY_PATH=/users/user/indy-sdk/libindy/target
```

By the way there is no config file under the target folder. I checked it and couldnt find any and no parent folder as /path or /to or /sdk which is confusing.

But then when I move forward with the next steps:

```
    cd /indy-sdk/cli. 
    cargo build
```

It gave me these error messages:

```
    error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
```

[terminal ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e42O.png)

```
    could not compile `indy-cli` (bin "indy-cli") due to previous 
    error
```

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
```

I got stuck I appreciate any help.

Uninstalled and reinstalled rust

Answer (score 1):

solved!!

followed the setup guide here [link](https://hyperledger-indy.readthedocs.io/projects/sdk/en/latest/docs/build-guides/mac-build.html)! with few exceptions please see them below:

at step1:

```
    brew install libsodium
    brew instal openssl@1.1
```

at step4:

```
    export OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1u
```

at step6 (note that your indy-sdk folder can be cloned to a different directory so arrange it accordingly):

```
    export LIBRARY_PATH=/users/user/indy-sdk/libindy/target/debug
```